a mistake in the book or a deficiency?
Our source book : A Practical English Grammar 4. by A. J. Thomson
it describes the perfect tense
I'm quoting as it is :
B Sometimes, however, the action finishes at the time of speaking:

(on meeting someone): /I haven't seen you for ages.
(but I see you now )

This room hasn't been cleaned for months. (but we are
cleaning it now) ??

It has been very cold lately but it's just beginning to get warmer.


In example 2, I can also think of it as the room still hasn't been cleaned.
Because the following example comes to mind :
He has lived here for months
Is there something missing in the book or am I thinking wrong?

“I can also think of it as the room still hasn't been cleaned.” The same could be said of #1, if it were written in a letter rather than spoken face to face. But both #1 and #2 have parenthetical comments describing the utterances’ contexts.

We'd need more context with "He has lived here for months" to know whether he's going somewhere else at time of speaking, or planning to live there for many more months (OR - he died this morning! :)

No, there is neither a mistake nor a deficiency in the book.
The passage you quote is pointing out that the perfect tense can be used for both things that are finishing now and for things that are ongoing. I don't know the book, but I'm willing to bet that "Section A" (immediately before the section B that you quote) tells you that the perfect tense can be used when an action continues to the present.
The examples they are giving are ones where the action might be finishing now, and are intended to point out that the perfect can be used whether or not the action is finishing now.
To extend your examples:

It's been very cold lately

is correct whether the weather is still very cold or whether it is now much warmer.

If we are about to clean a room, preparing to clean a room, a room that has not been cleaned in a long time, we can say "This room has not been cleaned in a long time." And even while we are in the act of cleaning the room we can say "This room has not been cleaned in a long time." We can say that even as we are dusting the bookshelves and washing the windows. It is only when the cleaning of the room has been completed that we can no longer say "This room has not been cleaned in a long time". Once we have cleaned the room, once our cleaning of the room is complete, we must say "The room had not been cleaned in a long time. Now that it has been cleaned, it is clean."
